# visual studio 2010 express registration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, registration

I'm not able to get registration key for visual studio 2010 express (or 2012 express).

If I'm clicking the "get registration key" in visual studio and the browser tells me "page not found".

This is the link VS tries to open: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163982

Can anyone tell me how to get registration key?

Many thanks!

I used the offline installer (from DVD) - registration is required anyway (It seams that some people think in that case no key is reqired ...)

Comment: Why not try using VS 2013 Community Edition? Its better and full featured

Answer (score 0):

You should get Visual Studio 2012 Express free from Microsoft website by telling you're a student. In alternative you can register for Microsoft Dreamspark And can get VS 2013 Professional for free.
You can get one Community version of Visual Studio 2013 Here;

https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Its FREE for Students.